# Getting "Tor won't work with this browser" message

Tags: configuration, error, mac

When I start TOR I get the message on the start page "Something went wrong, Tor won't work with browser". I have included LOG INFO below:

```
4/22/17, 1:51:19.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop 
4/22/17, 1:51:20.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit 
4/22/17, 1:51:23.100 [NOTICE] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working. 
4/22/17, 1:51:23.100 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 100%: Done 
4/22/17, 1:51:24.500 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1. 
4/22/17, 1:54:07.700 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1.
```

Comment: What is your question? How are you using Tor? Your question needs more information plus an actual question to receive a good answer. Please edit your question and add more information.

Comment: I apologize for the lack if info in my question. I have been using Tor for a long time without issues. I was trying to set up i2P (Snark) for downloading files. I tried to follow instructions and was told to make changes to my Firefox browser and do something with "new" proxies. As I do not have a high IT IQ, I probably shouldn't have messed with this. After making the changes (perhaps wrong), and restarted, when I try and open Tor, I get the Tor window that says "Something went wrong, Tor is not working in this browser." I've reinstalled Tor and Firefox but still get same message. Thank You

Comment: Please explain what steps you did when changing the config (or provide a link to the instructions you followed). Do you use Tor Browser (which version)?